# Verify everything is functioning in my full node

Tags: bitcoind, full-node, installation

This is a newbie question, sorry.
I recently bought Bitcoin and thought I would do something to support the system that I have invested money in. So I bought the hardware to run a full node.
I just finished installing a full node on an Ubuntu machine.
The IBD finished. Full txn idx, everything.
I didn’t see any obvious errors. Everything seems fine. Blocks seem to be keeping up when viewed using Bitcoin-cli. I don’t see obvious errors in the debug.log.
I’m going to let it run 24/7.
Could someone please tell me exactly how I verify (sanity check) this install and runtime so that I know it is actually working and useful.
What do I look for to see that it is keeping up with new data, is consistent and being used correctly. Pointless if it is not.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you know IBD finished?

Comment: sorry, getting used to this system .... @Pieter, When I started the IBD, I got messages in the debug.log that told me when headers and then blocks had finished loading. Sorry, I cannot post the messages here as they have rolled off the log. Next, if I issue the command bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo, I see the following in the output ... "initialblockdownload": false ... and the output also show the number of headers and blocks to be the same value , but increasing as time goes on.  That all looks good but I was looking for a definitive way to check the health of my install and run-time.